# Arrays of objects help! (array type being resolved to a class type)

Tags: java, arrays, types

Ok, so I have a class A and a class B, and class A contains an array of B's, here is my code to add a new B in the array.

```
public void addNewB(B b){
  course[noOfBs]= b;
  noOfBs++;
}
```

Java says 'The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to B'

My theory to add to the array was since the noOfB's is the next empty index in the array
(assuming none have been removed) so this code would just place the B in the next empty slot.

Why does this not work?! :(
(sorry about the poor layout, I couldn't work out this site!)

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the variables course and noOfBs ?

Comment: *"(sorry about the poor layout, I couldn't work out this site!)"* There's **lots** of formatting information on the page where you type this question. All you have to do to format code is indent it with four spaces. Done.

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that the type of your variable `course` is actually `B`, not `B[]`. Look at the declaration - I'm pretty sure you'll find it looks like this:

```
B course;
```

If that's not the case, please edit your question to include the declaration.

Also, consider using a `List<B>`, so you can use:

```
public void addNewB(B b) {
    course.add(b);
}
```

... and remove your `noOfBs` variable entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are doing something wrong. Since u have not the given the complete information. I will presume that ur declarations or ur way of calling the function may be wrong. This should work.

```
B course[]=new B[MAX_COURSES]; /* This declares an array of refereneces */

public void addNewB(B b){
  course[noOfBs]= b;
  noOfBs++;
}
```

Calling the function:

```
B course1=new B(); b.setCourseName("....") /* Make the object of B */
addNew(course1);
```